# Решение дилеммы с множественными копиями EXCEL в фоне

Tags: c#, excel

Суть проблемы в том что в приложение нужно добавить функцию поиска информации в документе, ориентируясь на имя файла. С этим проблем нет. Но вот в чём незадача: при запуске каждой копии приложения и попытке найти информацию в документе, в фоне будет запускаться новая копия приложения EXCEL с нужным документом. Документ очень большой и если запускать каждый раз новый EXCEL для каждой новой копии моего приложения, то они будут нехило отжирать память, да и сам EXCEL запускается с заметной задержкой. Что бы избежать кучи EXCEL в фоне, можно его закрывать после каждого обращения, но это будет ещё более неудобно, так как если работать в 1 копии программы, то будет каждый раз сильная задержка. Есть ли какой-то элегантный способ что бы заставить работать только с 1 копией EXCEL всем запущенным программам? Единственный вариант, который я вижу - это отдельное приложение-сервер, которое само откроет один раз документ и будет принимать запросы от клиентов и показывать информацию из таблицы. Ну или оставить как есть и объяснить пользователям, что бы не злоупотребляли?

Comment: У вас задача сводится только к поиску чего-то? Я бы не парился бы и воспользовался EpPlus и ушел бы от зависимости использования самого Excel, что сразу минус много проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользователям ничего объяснять не надо, современные версии Excel при открытии документов через свой интерфейс или в проводнике и так открывают их все в одном процессе, если им особым образом не указать делать по другому. Что касается программного открытия, конечно, несколько экземпляров программы также могут работать с одним экземпляром Excel. Это делается примерно так:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

//...

public static Excel.Application GetExcelInstance()
{ 
    Excel.Application app=null;           

    try
    {
        app = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
    }
    catch (COMException) { app = null; }

    if(app == null) app = new Excel.Application();
    return app;
}
```

Comment: Отлично работает, но при попытке закрыть активную книгу получаю исключение, если убрать закрытие книги перед выходом из эксэля, то норм всё. Единственное что даже после закрытия всех копий программы эксэл висит в процессах. Решилось добавлением после команды xl_App.Quit(); строчки xl_App = null;. Вроде работает, но выглядит как костыль.

Comment: С данным кодом возникает проблема, если до этого был открыть эксэль обычным образом, то он закроется вместе с программой.

Comment: @corvered Естественно, при данном подходе вы должны закрывать только то, что сами открывали, и вызывать метод Quit только когда программа реально создает новый процесс Excel (т.е. когда выполнялась строчка `app = new Excel.Application();`).